# How quickly does Researcher's Coat increase the EXP rate?

Tags: holocure-save-the-fans

The description for the Researcher's Coat item states

> Gain 1% EXP per 2 seconds. When HP is full, the EXP rate slowly increases to 2% and is reset to 1% when taking damage.

How long does it take for the EXP rate to increase?